# Git Failing to Resolve Hostname for Pull and Clone

Tags: git, bitbucket

A coworker is experiencing an issue where they are unable to perform a `git pull` within a previously working repository and also unable to `git clone` the repository.

For both cases they receive the following error:

```
Cloning into 'repository-name' ...
ssh: Could not resolve hostname bitbucket: Name or service not known.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

We have confirmed that he has repository access and the SSH key is configured correctly (even generated a new key). This issue just started occurring after no issues for 2 years.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There were two issues:

1. Unable to clone the repository.
2. Unable to pull within the existing local repository clone.

The first issue was fortunately resolved by restarting the computer, though generating the new SSH key beforehand *may* have contributed.

The second issue was a bit more obscure. After more digging into the settings it was found that the `.git/config` within the local repository was misconfigured.

The `[remote "origin"]` was improperly set to:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = username@bitbucket.org:company/repository.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Note that the `url` is incorrect. Updating the config to the proper values resolved the issue with the local repository.

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@bitbucket.org:company/repository.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Still unsure of what went wrong, but fortunately everything is working again.